# i keep receiving an environment error in pip, how to fix it?

Tags: python-3.x

environment error pip install[enter image description here][1]

I have been trying to install TensorFlow packages with the command prompt using 'pip' but I keep getting an environment error

Comment: Please fix your image.

Comment: Please post the error message as text, not as an image. Images should be used only when the problem can't be demonstrated any other way. Images are not searchable, and are difficult for those who are using screen readers or on mobile devices.

Comment: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Emma\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorflow_estimator\\python\\estimator\\canned\\linear_optimizer\\python\\utils\\__pycache__\\sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.cpython-38.pyc'